# Porque que o meu modal não aparece?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--INICIO DO PRELOADER-->
  <div class="loader-wrapper">
    <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
  </div>
  <!--FIM DO PRELOADER-->
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Não aparece pq vc tem que acioná-lo!

Comment: Você tem que chamá-lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentação sobre modal:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/

Está faltando o botão para chamar o modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">
  Botão
</button>
```

e inserir o id no modal

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modal1">
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">
  Botão
</button>

<div class="content">
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modal1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Título do modal</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Seu conteúdo aqui...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--INICIO DO PRELOADER-->
  <div class="loader-wrapper">
    <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
  </div>
  <!--FIM DO PRELOADER-->
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
```